# How to get dynamic security privileges with Symfony Security

Tags: symfony, security, roles, access-control

I'm need to do add custom access law to my access control on Symfony, I try to explain me.
I have a web application with some customer, and I want to able the access of some part of the code when that customer have the right plugin. So this is my customer:

```
namespace AppBundle\Entity;

class CustomerProfile{

private $id;

private $user;

private $plugins;
}
```

The Entity for the Plugin

```
namespace AppBundle\Entity;

class Plugin{

private $id;

private $name;

private $customerProfiles;
}
```

I use doctrine for the relations so from customer i can get his plugins. For example, we have 2 customer and 2 plugin:

```
AppBundle\Entity\CustomerProfile:
customer_1:
    user: '@user_1'
    plugins: ['@plugin_1','@plugin_2']
customer_2:
    user: '@user_2'
    plugins: ['@plugin_1']

AppBundle\Entity\Plugin:
plugin_1:
    name: 'plugin 1' 
plugin_2:
    name: 'plugin 2'
```

In my project all the code about customer is under the /customer namespace, Symfony like, and all work.

```
access_control:
    - { path: ^/customer, roles: ROLE_CUSTOMER }
```

But, for this customer with different plugin i would set an dinamic access control, but i don't know how. I need to control something like this:

```
access_control:
    - { path: ^/code_for_plugin_1, roles: ROLE_CUSTOMER_WHIT_PLUGIN_1}
    - { path: ^/code_for_plugin_2, roles: ROLE_CUSTOMER_WHIT_PLUGIN_2}
```

but I think the good way is set a "sub role" (if exist) to set for each customer that have a plugin a role to access in that namespace.

I hope I was clear enough, thanks for help.

Comment: You probably need a voter. http://symfony.com/doc/current/security/voters.html

Comment: Or maybe you could simply implement `CustomerProfile::getRoles` to return also dynamically assigned roles basing on plugins.

Comment: i'm already reading that doc, I hope will be the right way. I think the login in getRoles is not good, because in real case i have 5-6 different plugin (that will scape up in future) and a lot of customer, so i don't want to create a different ROLE for each combination of plugin, that would be ugly and not efficient.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest to use custom voter rather than the `access_control` and role approach as
this is in my opinion more flexible for your use case. Your suggested solution requires
a generated role (`ROLE_CUSTOMER_WHIT_PLUGIN_{X}`) for every plugin, which in case
of adding pluggins dynamically would just not work.

Check the [How to Use Voters to Check User Permissions](http://symfony.com/doc/2.8/security/voters.html) article in Symfony documentation for more detail.

You basically need to implement a user voter which will check if the logged user has an access
to requested resource. In your case it would look similar to this:

**/src/YourBundle/Controller/YourController.php**

```
<?php

...

class YourController extends Controller
{

    public function getFooAction($id)
    {
        $this->denyAccessUnlessGranted(YourVoter::VIEW_FOO);

        // ...method logic
    }

    public function getBarAction($id)
    {
        $this->denyAccessUnlessGranted(YourVoter::VIEW_BAR);

        // ...method logic
    }
}
```

**/src/YourBundle/Security/YourVoter.php**

```
<?php

...

class YourVoter extends AbstractVoter
{
    const VIEW_FOO = 'YOUR_VIEW_FOO';
    const VIEW_BAR = 'YOUR_VIEW_BAR';

    public function getVoterAttributes()
    {
        return [self::VIEW_FOO, self::VIEW_BAR,];
    }

    protected function supports($attribute, $subject)
    {
        ...
    }

    protected function voteOnAttribute($attribute, $item, TokenInterface $token)
    {
        $user = $token->getUser();
        if (!$user instanceof User) {
            return false;
        }

        switch ($attribute) {
            case self::VIEW_FOO:
                return $this->canViewFoo($user);
            case self::VIEW_BAR:
                return $this->canViewBar($user);
        }

        throw new \Exception(sprintf(
            'Invalid vote attribute "%s".',
            $attribute
        ));
    }

    private function canViewFoo(User $user)
    {
        return $user->getProfile()->hasRoleFooXYZ()
    }


    private function canViewBar(User $user)
    {
        return $user->getProfile()->hasRoleBarXYZ()
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I read you answer and the doc (I have already reading) and I have one doubt: I think I know how voter works: it able or disable an action on a Entity (o simple class) from an user through my own logic. My plugin are a group of action customer can do, but modify mi structure I can go back to the specify class of each Plugin. So, I must call the voter in each action? If I forget to do my security is violated? This voter is not call on class every action on that class? this would be very usefull.

Comment: Also I think to use the both control: with role on the route and with voter on the class. But i must study voter deeper to know well about.

Comment: Yes, every accessible action should have a security check. You need to check permissions with `$this->denyAccessUnlessGranted()` or `$this->isGranted()` methods. You can combine both access controls as you mentioned, too.